# How to initialise a BackboneJS model that has no defaults?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've found myself doing a lot of these, for instance:

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({

});

var sampleItemCode = 12345;

var item = new Item({itemCode: sampleItemCode});
```

I have no defaults for any of the attributes that I want to set, and yet I want to make it its own model. It looks weird to have an empty Backbone.Model like that, so I'm wondering if there is a good way to initialise it?

Comment: are you using/checking for the class `Item` later? Why not just `new Backbone.Model({itemCode: 12345});`?

Comment: I want to leave the structure for future code which might require additions to the model

Answer (score 1):

Better have it like this.

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({    
    defaults: {itemCode: -1}
});
```

itemCode is definite need for an item. So default it. So when you write some functions inside `Item` model, you'll always have itemCode and you can check against it. And when you fetch data from server for collection  and if that item don't have itemCode OR when you initialize Item and if you failed to set itemCode, it'll always have it's default.

For example, if you are adding new item to your collection. You can do just like this.

```
collection.push(new Item({name: "Item 56", price: 1500}));
```

here you don't need to pass itemCode: -1 on each time. It'll be defaulted and when you save, in server, you can check itemCode and if it is -1, you can consider it as new item add.

But nothing wrong to have it like you did. You'll surely add functions to that model when you extend your app.